# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, nonetype

There is a website with this html-code and only one itemprop="brand":

```
<dd itemprop="brand" class="attributeValue-2574930263">
    <a class="link-3970392289 link__default-1151936189 attributeLink-2414863004" href="/b- 
    cars-trucks/ottawa/hyundai/c174l1700185a54">Hyundai</a>
</dd>
```

I can not use classes, because there are many of theme.
I am trying to get the text (Hyundai) with this code:

```
def get_car_datas(url):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    car_brand = soup.find(itemprop_="brand").next_elements
    print(car_brand)
```

I get this message:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_elements'

How can I get the text Hyundai?

Comment: When `soup.find(itemprop_="brand")` is called, it seems to have returned `None`, which does not have any attributes, unlike classess. You don't want that function to return None then.

Comment: I would examine the response content and verify it contains what you think it does

Comment: Is this from Kijiji? The link format looks familiar.

Comment: @Amolgorithm Yes, I answered with the full code

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the find() method. Instead of using **itemprop_**="brand", you should use **itemprop**="brand".

Answer (score 0):

this error means that Beautifulsoup is not able to find the given element.

Try this:

```
def get_car_datas(url):
   req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   src = req.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
   try:
      car_brand = soup.find(itemprop_="brand").next_elements
      print(car_brand)
   except:
      car_brand = "<div> No elements found </div>"
      print(car_brand)
```

Comment: He writes only No elements found. Still can't get the text "Hyundai".

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because `soup.find(itemprop_="brand")` has not found any element with `itemprop_="brand"`, therefore returning None. Since None does not have an attribute called `next_elements`, this error is thrown.

First of all, you have a type, as mentioned by Teroaz. You are searching for `itemprop`, not `itemprop_`. So you could do this (but you have another option below):

```
def get_car_datas(url):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    car_brand = soup.find(itemprop="brand")

    if car_brand:
        car_brand = car_brand.next_elements
        print(car_brand)
    else:
        print("Brand not found :(")
```

This might be more explicit on what you are searching for, so you could do this:

```
def get_car_datas(url):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    car_brand = soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "brand"})

    if car_brand:
        car_brand = car_brand.next_elements
        print(car_brand)
    else:
        print("Brand not found :(")
```

It may work better. Or, if you'd like, you could stick to the option above.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying with only one page. Some times the respond is the text I am searching for (Hyundai, BMW, Kia...), some times it is responding "Brand not found :(".
Here is the full code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0Safari/537.36"
}

def get_car_datas(url):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    car_brand = soup.find(attrs={"itemprop": "brand"})
    if car_brand:
        car_brand = car_brand.find(class_="link-3970392289").text
        print(car_brand)
    else:
        print("Brand not found :(")

page_number = 0
for page_number in range(1, 2):
    url = f"https://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/ontario/suv/2017__/page-{page_number}/k0c174l9004a68?price=__25000&kilometers=__80000"
    page_number += 1
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    page_number_text = soup.find(class_="pagination").text
    if "Next" in page_number_text:
        get_car_links = soup.find_all(class_="info-container")
        for i in get_car_links:
            if not "https" in i.find('a', class_='title').get('href'):
                car_links = i.find("a", class_="title")
                car_url = ('https://www.kijiji.ca' + car_links.get("href"))
                get_car_datas(car_url)
                print(car_url)
        print(f"Page {page_number-1} done!")
        continue
    else:
        get_car_links = soup.find_all(class_="info-container")
        for i in get_car_links:
            car_links = i.find("a", class_="title")
            car_url = ('https://www.kijiji.ca' + car_links.get("href"))
        print("Last page done!")
        break
```